# Java Swing paintComponent() override

Tags: java, swing

I want to set an Image as background in some `JComponent` (`JPanel`, `JLayeredPane`,..). To do that I created the class `JImagePanel` that extends `JPanel` and overrides the method. Same thing for the other components. I now have 3 classes that differ only for what they extend. I wanted to create a unique class `JImageComponent` that extends `JComponent`, and then all the others will extend it, but I can't since the classes I created already extend a class (`JImagePanel` extends `JPanel`). Is there any other way I can do that?

This is the code of one of the classes I created:

```
public class JImagePanel extends JPanel {

  private static final int DEFAULTX = 0;
  private static final int DEFAULTY = 0;
  private static final int DEFAULTWIDTH = 1100;
  private static final int DEFAULTHEIGHT = 700;

  private BufferedImage img;
  private int imagex;
  private int imagey;
  private int imagewidth;
  private int imageheight;
  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

  public JImagePanel(String path){
        super();
        this.imagex=JImagePanel.DEFAULTX;
        this.imagey=JImagePanel.DEFAULTY;
        this.imagewidth=JImagePanel.DEFAULTWIDTH;
        this.imageheight=JImagePanel.DEFAULTHEIGHT;
        img = loadImage(path);
  }

  public JImagePanel(String path,int x,int y, int width, int height){
        super();
        this.imagex=x;
        this.imagey=y;
        this.imagewidth=width;
        this.imageheight=height;
        img = loadImage(path);
  }

  @Override
  protected void paintComponent(Graphics graphics) {
        super.paintComponent(graphics);

       setOpaque(false);
       graphics.drawImage(img, imagex, imagey,imagewidth,imageheight, null);
  }
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: I'm confused: why *exactly* can't you have all your other image-displaying class extend from this one? Why can't you re-write them to extend this one? What is the difference in all their functionalities? Note that you should not be setting opaqueness from within paintComponent, but rather from the constructor.

Comment: The problem is that all the classes have to extend from their "natural parent" class (for example JImagePanel is still a JPanel and must extend it), therefore i cannot create just one class with this function and then extends it. I am sorry, maybe I haven't understood your question. And Thanks, I will set the opaqueness in the constructor!

Comment: I would like to have just one class because I don't want to have duplicated code.

Comment: As you know Java doesn't allow multiple inheritance, and so your choices as I see it: have all components extend from this JImagePanel (you still have not explained why the other classes *must* extend from JComponent and not JPanel), or use composition instead of inheritance to enhance your classes.

Answer (score 0):

What you are suggesting isn't logically possible since `JPanel`, `JLayeredPane`, etc. already extend `JComponent`. What you're trying to do is add a new step in the hierarchy. Right now it goes `JImagePanel -->JPanel --> JComponent`, etc. and you're trying to make it `JImagePanel --> JPanel --> JImageComponent --> JComponent`. To do this, you would have to change the `JPanel` class so it actually extends `JImageComponent`.

Here's my suggestion:
Don't use `JImageComponent` on the classes that already extend components. If you make new components that don't extend pre-existing components, have them extend `JImageComponent`, or `JComponent` directly. If the purpose of your `JImageComponent` class was to provide unity to your elements, consider making an interface for all your elements to implement.